# Why is using Scanner.next() causing this odd System.out.println() behavior?

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

While attempting the [final project for my friend's ICS class](https://www2.hawaii.edu/~walbritt/ics211/materials/project.htm), I've come across this strange bug.

One of the tasks was to read [this CSV file](https://www2.hawaii.edu/~walbritt/ics211/materials/input-project.csv). This is a short SSCCE of how I did it using a Scanner:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fileScanner;
        String inputFile = "input-project.csv";

        try {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
            fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            fileScanner.nextLine();

            while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                String name = fileScanner.next();
                String number = fileScanner.next();
                System.out.println("Inserting " + name + " " + number + " (" + hash(name) + ")");
                //telephoneBook.insert(name, number);
            }

            fileScanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Input file " + inputFile + " was not found");
        }
    }

    public static Integer hash(String name) {
        return name.hashCode() % 7;
    }
}
```

It reads fine, but for some reason `System.out.println("Inserting " + name + " " + number + " (" + hash(name) + ")")` only prints `" (" + hash(name) + ")"`.

Take a look at this output:

```
 (5)
 (1)
 (4)
 (5)
 (3)
 (1)
 (4)
 (2)
 (2)
 (2)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

While playing around with the code trying to fix this problem, I ended up fixing it by **not using `fileScanner.next()`**. This is my current working example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fileScanner;
        String inputFile = "input-project.csv";

        try {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
            //fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]"); 
            fileScanner.nextLine(); // skip the first line

            while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                String[] line = fileScanner.nextLine().split(",");
                String name = line[0];
                String number = line[1];
                //String name = fileScanner.next();
                //String number = fileScanner.next();
                System.out.println("Inserting " + name + " " + number + " (" + hash(name) + ")");
                //telephoneBook.insert(name, number);
            }

            fileScanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Input file " + inputFile + " was not found");
        }
    }

    public static Integer hash(String name) {
        return name.hashCode() % 7;
    }
}
```

This prints out as expected:

```
Inserting HALL 123-4566 (5)
Inserting BAKER 111-1111 (1)
Inserting CARTER 222-2222 (4)
Inserting KING 555-5555 (5)
Inserting FOX 666-6666 (3)
Inserting LEE 777-7777 (1)
Inserting CASTRO 888-8888 (4)
Inserting DAVIS 999-9999 (2)
Inserting LONG 987-1234 (2)
Inserting KAM 654-7890 (2)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My question now is: **Why does this fix the problem?** Was I using the `.next()` method incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV file you've linked has CRLF line terminators, however your delimiter only catches `\n`. So, the `\r` makes it into your string and makes the output formatting look strange. Instead, try using a different delimiter:

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter(",|\r?\n");
```